# Are persistent connections used?

Tags: 7, database

How can I find out whether my Drupal 7 site using persistent connection or not? And it's possible to turn it on if it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the persistent connections is not enabled you can enable it by adding this to settings.php:

```
ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent', TRUE);
```

And you just do like this to turn it off:

```
ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent', TRUE);
```

To check is persistent connections is enabled go to `/admin/reports/status/php`, and search for `allow_persistent`.

Comment: Thank you. How can I check whether it really works or not? Maybe somewhere in Drupal logs/reports